# Is there any performance gain when using Indexer for Objects?

Tags: c#, indexer

Suppose if I have to make three objects for a class flyweight, what is the difference between making an object like this

```
flyweight f1=new flyweight();
flyweight f2=new flyweight();
flyweight f3=new flyweight();
```

and like this?

```
public class flyweight
{
    flyweight[] obj = new flyweight[3];
    public flyweight this[int index]
    {
        get{
            if (index < 3) {
                obj[index] = new flyweight();
            }
            return obj[index];
        }
    }
    public void display() {
        Console.WriteLine("this is a object");
    }
    public void load() {
        flyweight f = new flyweight();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            f[i].display();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any performance gain when we use Indexer for creating objects?

Comment: Please don't quote pieces of text which aren't really quotes, such as your question at the end. I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: This is very strange code, as a flyweight is usually immutable - whereas you're using the flyweight as a factory for other flyweights, which is distinctly unusual.

Comment: The two chunks of code do very different things, but the general rule is write clear understandable code and set performance goals. Then, once the code clearly does the correct thing (impossible to tell whether either of your code samples does currently since we don't know the spec), *measure* the performance. Only if it doesn't meet the goals should you start assessing alternatives.

Comment: I don't get your get property, why are you initializing a new flyweight object every time. With the current code you have, the former solution would be faster.

Comment: You are making things complicated with the alternative approach, and not in a good way. As written, `obj` is an **instance** variable meaning that **first** you have to create a `flyweight` instance, which then manages **other** instances using `obj` and the indexer. Not only do you now end up with 4 instances, on top of that **each** of them has an `obj` variable. Total mess... Looks like you typed it all as you went into the SO Question box... never do!

Comment: @JonSkeet this was just an example, all i wanted to know is if i use an indexer as shown in the example to create three object will that gain performance? will the object take low space compared to the former example?

Comment: "Just an example" doesn't mean it's a good idea to ignore naming conventions and make your aims unclear. The use of an indexer in particular is irrelevant - just imagine you were using a method instead of an indexer, and the result would be absolutely the same.

Comment: @JonSkeet we are new to c# and are still learning, please forgive us if we did some mistake, i would like to learn all the patterns and the benefits of using them, your answer will help me as well as someone who is still learning like me.. thank you :)

Comment: Well as I say, you would be best off learning and using the .NET naming conventions to start with. But it's unclear why you think using an indexer to create objects would be better than doing it directly. What do you think is special about an indexer?

Comment: @JonSkeet i was going through this link for learning design patterns in c# http://www.kitabxana.net/files/books/file/1330505636.pdf and was informed that flyweight creates minimum object and the example which i metioned is the example the have mentioned about the Flyweight pattern

Comment: But you haven't implemented the flyweight pattern as shown in the book. Your indexer *always* creates a new object (if the index is valid)... and for some reason you've combined the flyweight type itself with the factory, for no obvious reason. I think you should go back to the book and reread the description of the pattern. The key isn't that it uses an indexer - it's that it creates objects only when required, and retains them for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

An index property is compiled as a simple `public flyweight get_Item(int index)` method. Calling a method is not faster than accessing variables `f1`, `f2` and `f3` directly (although I do not have proof for that).

If you optimize on this level, without evidence of performance issues, you'll probably end up with a *slower* application full of bugs because your application layout is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

If anything you could use a double approach, using both instance variables and an array:

```
var f1 = new flyweight();
var f2 = new flyweight();
var f3 = new flyweight();
var flyweights = new[] { f1, f2, f3 };
```

This allows to use specific instances if you need to, and iterate over all of them where that might be useful.